# Disable cache in browser

Tags: caching, browser, safari

**Issue**

I work a lot with stylesheets, I change something and I check how it looks. However most if not all current browsers, store the stylesheet and thus won't let me see the differences. Only with a lot of Reset Safari, Empty Cache button presses it suddenly updates but this is really annoying.

**Question**

Is there a way to disable the cache feature in browsers? So it won't store any files and I will always fetch the latest css from the server.

Ps. Safari's Empty Cache and Reset Safari doesn't always clear the cache and Develop > Disable Cache doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: We have also noticed that Empty Cache and Develop > Disable Cache doesn't do anything, for sure. We are remotely debugging a page on an iPhone from a Mac desktop computer. With other device (namely Android phones), remote debugging with Chrome and having cache disabled via developer tools works like a charm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Chrome, IE, Firefox, and most other browsers, `Ctrl+F5` ("hard refresh") will force reloading cached resources on the page. I do this all the time. I can't speak for Safari, but I'd expect it would do the same.

**Edit**: I just did a search for "+Safari +hard +refresh" and it looks like on the Mac, you [hold down the `Options`](http://ascherconsulting.com/how/do/i/perform/a/hard/refresh/in/safari/) key [while clicking refresh](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=77086). Some sources [say `Shift` also works](http://www.quora.com/Is-hard-refresh-%E2%8C%98-%E2%87%A7-R-in-Safari-5-gone), and that [`Command+Option+E` clears cache](http://www.kelpdesign.com/tech-talk/what-are-the-hard-refresh-shortcuts-for-a-mac-using-safari-and-firefox/).

Comment: Is that also for MAC the case or don't you know that? Since in Windows you have CTRL+C and on mac its CMD+C

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to T.J. Crowder for [helping me in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662367) - I figured it out.

On Windows you can, in fact, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to force the browser to refresh.

On Mac Safari you can hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button, then press the refresh button to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just found that in the latest version of Safari for macOS, you can press Cmd+Option+R to hard refresh (as opposed to the standard Cmd+R that refreshes with a cache). This is a game changer for me!

Cmd+Shift+R just opens the Reader View on my Mac.