# Is it possible to completely turn off caching in Safari or any modern browser?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, safari, web-inspector

I know it is possible to clear the cache in a browser via shortcuts: [Disable cache in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662357/disable-cache-in-browser). But it is possible to **completely** turn off caching in Safari or any modern browser? From my experience and the OSX process logs, Safari's "disable caches" option does not completely disable caches in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/3207478

this should do it:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```